# How to extend the Solution Explorer for showing additional information for custom files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, solution-explorer

I have a lot of files in my current project with a custom internal extension. It would be very helpful for me if the Solution Explorer of visual studio 2012 could show extended information about them (similar to how it shows information for the .cs files.) Is it possible to create an extension for the Explorer and where should I begin?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but did you click on the [visual-studio-extensions] tag you tagged this question with?

Answer (score 0):

I expect a great place to begin would be to look through [Mads Kristensen's WebEssentials](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/) repo.

It's a great extension that adds a number of customizations to the Solution Explorer, such as nesting minified js files under the originals.  It should be a great place to find more specific topics to ask questions about.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check the repo.